# getting href onclick

Tags: javascript

I am developing an extension for Mozilla Firefox. A main function is to get the URL that the user is visiting and process it later. I tried the following Javascript code:

```
window.onload = function(){
  alert(document.referrer);
}
```

That didnt work so I tried to inject an `onclick` event to every link using this:

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var links = document.links;
    for(var i=0;i<links.length;++i){  
        links[i].onclick = show_href();
    }
}

function show_href(){
    alert(this.href);    
}
```

But that also doesnt work. Any other approach?

Comment: but the problem with that is not all links are <a> there can be image links as-well
nevertheless i will try that too

Comment: In which context are you executing that script? Is `window` the content window or the browser window? You can check by doing `alert(window.location.href)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<a href="#xxx">linktextx</a>
<a href="#yyy">linktexty</a>
<a href="#zzz">linktextz</a>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    var links = document.links;
    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        links[i].onclick = function(){alert(this.href)};
      }
    }
</script>
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/uXmWj/ for working demo

Comment: It's not quite the same code.  This assigns an anonymous function to each link, rather than a named function.

Answer (score 0):

In the second approach, the problem could be the `for loop`.

```
window.onload = function(){
   var links = document.links,
       max,
       i;

   for(var i=0, max = links.length; i < max; i += 1) {
      (function() {
         var link = links[i];

         link.onclick = function() {
            alert(this.href);
         }
      })();
   }
};
```

Comment: Why, exactly, would a closure help? He's not "losing" the value of `i` at any point.

Answer (score 0):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for(var i=0,l=anchors.length;i<l;i++)
    if(anchors[i].hasAttribute('href'))
        anchors[i].onclick = function(){
            alert(anchors[i].getAttribute('href'));
        }
```